# Android Kotlin : automatically go next Audio . How?

Tags: android, audio, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I am going to implement an audio player. I can go next audio by manual clicking. Flow works. but when it comes to implementing this flow to background, my audio player does not work. The Media Plater cannot automatically move to the next audio file and play.

When the screen dims, the audio cannot continue  to search next audio if one audio chapter ends

Here is my method and code to go next audio .

```
mediaPlayer!!.setOnCompletionListener {
                    it.reset()
                    goNextAudio()
                }



private fun goNextAudio (){    
   stop()
   accessAudio(nextAudio )
}

 private fun stop(){
    if(mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying){
                isPLaying = false
                mediaPlayer!!.stop()
                mediaPlayer!!.release()
                mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                seekBarAudio.progress = 0
            }
    }



   private fun accessAudio (audio : Audio) {
     ..
     get next audio file
     mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mediaPlayer!!.setDataSource(file.path);
            mediaPlayer!!.prepare();

}
```

Comment: mediaPlayer!!.setOnCompletionListener {
                    it.reset()
                    goNextAudio()
                }
-On completion you are calling goNextAudio() that's why.

Comment: should I not to stop the media player?

Comment: Remove goNextAudio() from setOnCompletionListener and try it.

Comment: how can i change the data source then?

Comment: It dependes what you want to do after completion of media.

Comment: Then you should set data source on some other event or click of a view etc. Try removing that code and let me know it worked or not.

Comment: Methods inside setOnCompletionListener is not triggered at all. Poor news